# Writing to file in chunks periodically

Tags: qt, qfile, qbytearray

Currently I'm writing a huge `QByteArray` to a file **after** filling it out with data:

```
QByteArray my_ba;

// Fill out my_ba in some loops

path = "/some/path.data";
QFile file(path);
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
file.write(my_ba);
file.close();
```

Since my `QByteArray` can be in order of **GB**s, to reduce memory usage, I need to write my `QByteArray` to file **in chunks**.

Does Qt have any convenient tool to do so? Is there any standard practice?

Comment: Is this question about how to program a loop that writes chunks to a file? Or is it about how big the ideal chunk should be?

Comment: Why not just to write into the file while looping? open first do your loops and close the file when it's finished. also, consider to compress your data.

Comment: I think that's what [QTextStream::flush](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#flush) does, but I could be wrong.

Comment: QFile file("file.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream out(&file);
out << chunk;// in loop. Sorry for formatting. I wrote from smartphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing to file in chunks **periodically** like this:

```
for(unsigned int j = 0; j < Count; ++j) {

    // Fill out QByteArray my_ba in every single iteration of the loop

    // ...

    // But write my_ba only periodically and then clear it!
    // period is picked in such a way that writing to file will be done for every 1MB of data
    if( j % period == 0){
            if(file){
                file->write(my_ba);
                file->flush();
                my_ba.clear();
            }
        }

    // ...
}
```

I clear my `QByteArray` periodically by doing `my_ba.clear()` after writing its content to file, therefore my `QByteArray` will never get big and its **memory consumption** is hence reduced.